# react-native-modal make background flatlist clickable

Tags: react-native

I am opening a modal on every item clicked within the flatlist. This modal can be swipeable. But the problem background list items can't be clicked. I understand that modal is taking control of the screen, but the question is is it possible to have background list items clickable when a swipeable modal is open.

Note. I am using modal from 'react-native-modal'

Thank you in advance

here is the code

App.tsx

```
    const App = () => {
        
        const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => openModal(item)}>
                <View>
                    <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                    <Text>{item.thumbnail}</Text>
                    <Image style={styles.logo} source={{ uri: item.thumbnail }} />
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    
    const openModal = (item) => {
      
        console.log('modal', item)
        SetSelectedItem(item)
        SetModalVisible(true)
    }

    const closeModal = () => {
        console.log('close modal')
        SetSelectedItem(undefined)
        SetModalVisible(false)
    }

        return (
    
            <>
                <FlatList
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
                    data={videos}
                    renderItem={renderItem}
                />
    
                {modalVisible ?
                    <VideoModal modalVisible={modalVisible} selectedItem={selectedItem} onClose={closeModal} /> :
                    null
                }    
            </>
        )
    }
```

modal.tsx

```
import Modal from 'react-native-modal'

    const VideoModal : React.FC<props> = ({modalVisible, selectedItem, onClose}) =>{
    
        
        return (
    
             <View>
                    <Modal isVisible={modalVisible}
                        swipeDirection={'down'}
                        swipeThreshold={200}
                        onSwipeComplete={() => console.log('swiped')}
                        propagateSwipe={true}
                        onBackdropPress = {() => console.log("pressed back")}
                    >
                        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                            <Video
                                source={{
                                    uri: selectedItem.url
                                }}
                                controls={false}
                                resizeMode={'contain'}
                                style = {styles.video}
                                
                            />
                            <Button title="Hide modal" onPress={onClose} />
                        </View>
                    </Modal>
                </View> 
    
        )
    }
```

Comment: I think you can't click the background when a modal is open, modal content uses `flex: 1; ` refer the [code](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal/blob/1d8023df8bb74f0fe1c5dd59b4931a0a26bec2e7/src/modal.style.ts#L14)

Comment: Okay thanks. Shifted to bottom sheet